# Relation about Disk and Sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Definition of sphere and disk are following

\begin{align}
S^n =\{ (x_1 , \cdots x_{n+1}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | \sum x_i^2 =1 \} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
D^n =\{ (x_1 , \cdots x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} | \sum x_i^2 \leq 
1 \} 
\end{align}

In Algebraic topology class, Prof, says there is a following homemorphic relation
\begin{align}
D^n / S^{n-1} \simeq S^n
\end{align}
Here $\simeq$ means homemorphic.  Is it true?(Or i mistake the note?) In the above definition $D^n$ has $n$ dimension and $S^n$ is $n+1$ dimension, So in terms of dimension i felt uncomfortable.

Can anyone give some derivation or hint for above relation?

Also i want to know the $D^2 \simeq S^1$ is valid expression.

Further, i want to find some restriction such that

\begin{align}
S^2 \rightarrow S^1
\end{align}

Comment: $S^n$ is $n$-dimensional, but it is usually seen as a subset embedded in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. Think of $D^2/S^1$ as the result of taking a 2D disc (which is $D^2$) and joining the boundary (which is $S^1$, a circle) together at a point. That should give you a sphere, which is $S^2$.

Comment: @Tunococ Thanks. Then i guess $D^2 \simeq S^1$ is invalid expression. Is it right? In the definition of $S$, there is no interior points, so it seems to me above expression is invalid, i guess.

Comment: $D^2 \simeq S^1$ is not true. (It's a *valid expression* in some sense though.) I'm not sure about what you said about interior points. Are trying to show that $S^1$ and $D^2$ are not homeomorphic?

Comment: @Tunococ I try to show that $S^1$ and $D^2$ are homeomorphic, below Benjamin made an useful answer to my question. You said in some sense the $D^2 \simeq S^1$ is valid. I want to know what that means.

Comment: I meant that $D^2 \simeq S^1$ is a comprehensible sentence. It's just a false sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some intuition as to why $D^n/S^{n-1} \simeq S^n$ is true.

Observe that the boundary of $D^n$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$, so what this relationship is expressing is that if you glue the boundary of an $n$-dimensional ball to a point, what you get is the $n$-dimensional sphere. This can be nicely visualized in the case of $n=1$ and $n=2$. In the first case, you are simply gluing together the endpoints of an interval.

---

A relevant invariant you can use to see that $D^2$ and $S^1$ are not homeomorphic is to look at how loops can move around them. In $D^2$, any loop can be shrunk continuously to a point, but the same is not true in $S^1$. This argument is not rigorous just yet, but no doubt you have or will see it in the future.